# Actually I connected my django database sqlite3 to Mysql database and whenever I migrate I get this error

Tags: django

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
        HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See:
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
Operations to perform:

Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:

No migrations to apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this option to your database config:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'sql_mode': 'traditional',
    }
}
}
```

**Note:** Also it's not an error, it's a warning and will not stop your project from working.